# Compose multiplatform on android and browser

Tags: android, kotlin, browser, cross-platform, compose-multiplatform

Is compose multiplatform actually mautiplatform? Or it just supports different platforms through different codebases?

So if I build an android app ui using compose multiplatform, can i run the same code base on different platforms like android and the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compose Multiplatform is stable since a couple days now!

Stable only for Android and Desktop. iOS still in alpha phase, but it's already working, not ready for production yet tho.

For web, it's even earlier than iOS, still experimental.

Compose Multiplatform is a declarative UI framework, this means you are able to share your UI between different OS. Developed by [JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/compose-multiplatform/) is based on Kotlin for the logic and Jetpack Compose for the UI.

*Since it came out like two days ago, yesterday I tried it. IMO it has potential. The same app worked on Android, iOS and MacOS. Since it's Kotlin, it potentially can run everywhere Java is executed.*

**So the short answer is yes, you can share your logic and UI between different platforms.**

You can find tons of articles from the official JetBrains [website](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/category/multiplatform/), give it a look!